# Windows could not prepare the computer to boot into the next phase... - Version 5

Tags: windows, windows-7-upgrade

Version 5 since there are 4 other answers.

Windows Server 2008 R2 (Pretty much Win7) needed to be upgraded to 2012 R2 prior to upgrade to 2019. I've done this a number of times without any problem.

Installation would near finish then end with this:
[image: Windows could not prepare the computer to boot into the next phase of installation. To install Windows, restart the installation.]

System is a VMware ESXi virtual machine.  Looked for ideas but could find nothing that applied. I tried with 2012 and tried with vCD vs install on local OS from extracted ISO (usually the way I go).  Checked system files.  No strange hardware installed that I don't always use.

Answer (score 0):

I found this in the Application Event log:

[image: Mitigation: WipeGuard part of Sophos Endpoint Security (HitManPro)]

Disabled Sophos Endpoint Security Tamper Protection, stopped all services, now Windows Server 2012 R2 installs just fine and so much faster.

Comment: Once upgraded to 2012 R2, with Sophos Endpoint Protection enabled, upgrade to 2019 went flawlessly.  This can apply to Win7 to Win 8.1 to Win 10 also.